# "spawn ENOENT" error while connecting to svn from javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, svn

I'm developing a web server that should be able to connect to svn, gather and process data like change logs. I've found an npm module for node.js that is called '[svn-spawn](https://github.com/ddliu/node-svn-spawn)'. I have a local checkout of a project, located in the folder 'D:\Projects\TankBattles'. Everything looks good, but when I tried to get logs I received an error "**spawn ENOENT**" . Could you help me to resolve the error. I'm on Windows 8 x64.

```
var q = require('q');
var SVNClient = require('svn-spawn');
var client = new SVNClient({
    cwd: 'D:\Projects\TankBattles'
});

var repository = {
    log: function () {
        var deferred = q.defer();
        try {
            client.log([], function (err, data) {
                // err is "spawn ENOENT"
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    }
};

module.exports.repository = repository;
```

P.S. I'm new in node.js and can do something wrong.

Comment: OMG! Just replaced 'D:\Projects\TankBattles' on 'D:\\Projects\\TankBattles' and it becomes working!

Comment: just curious, is this for WoT game?